# Inject Route Action on Controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5.5

I've made a role middleware to check if user has a specific Role:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user() === null) {
            return response("Insufficient permissions", 401);
        }
        $actions = $request->route()->getAction();
        $roles = isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;
        if ($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return response("Insufficient permissions", 401);
    }
}
```

If I want to check for some role in a specific role it's easy. I only have to add the middleware and an additional action called `roles`. E. g.:

```
Route::get('payments/{id}/pay', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@aprove',
    'as' => 'payments.aprove',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => [User::ADMINISTRATOR, User::SPOT_MANAGER, User::SELECTION_PROCESS_MANAGER],
]);
```

Doing this way works as expected. However, I have some routes that are `Route::resource` instead of `get`, `post`, or something like this. Laravel don't allow for specifying `roles => [...]` in resource.

The documentation says that if I want to inject middleware on resources I [should do this on controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#controller-middleware). But I can't specify `roles => [...]` as I used to do in normal routes anywhere! How could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you dont have control over the 'action' array to use when defining resource routes, and the middleware paremeters are not fitting you can define your own `ResourceRegistrar` and bind it to the container so the router will use it on `Route::resource` calls.

You will extend `Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar` and override the `getResourceAction` method to check the `$options` array to see if ... lets say a key named `action` is defined. If so merge this array into the `$action` array and now all the routes defined via `Route::resource` can accept an options key of `action` that takes your extra action values.

Allows for a definition like:

```
Route::resource('blah', 'BlahController', [
    'action' => ['roles' => ['admin', 'editor']]
]);
```

Something like this 'should' do:

```
protected function getResourceAction($resource, $controller, $method, $options)
{
    $action = parent::getResourceAction($resource, $controller, $method, $options);

    if (isset($options['action'])) {
        $action += $options['action'];
    }

    return $action;
}
```

In a service provider at `register` the binding:

```
$this->app->bind(
    \Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar::class,
    \App\Your\ResourceRegistrar::class
);
```

You could take that further and make it specific to roles so you could do this instead:

```
Route::resource('blah', 'BlahController', ['roles' => ['admin', 'editor']]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this by using middleware parameters, so you can pass parameters to your middleware. This 'action' method is a nice work around for some things but middleware take paremeters so there really isn't a need unless you need those params in more places.

```
'middleware' => 'roles:admin,editor,...'
```

Literally the example for middleware parameters in the docs is a user role check.

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Middleware - Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#middleware-parameters)

Also there is no 'injection'. You are just telling the router you want middleware, there isn't anything injected into anything else.

Comment: I read about this in the docs, but it's ugly to pass parameters this way.

Comment: unless you want to make your own ResourceRegistrar you aren't going to get very far with resource routing.